# Is there a way to trigger an animation or class change when a specific string is typed on typed.js

Tags: javascript, css, typed.js

I would like to trigger the appearance of a string whenever a certain string is typed with typed.js, I would like to know if it is possible to do this with typed.js or if I should use an alternative method.

I have tried timing the typing with the appearance of the button, but I would like to have a method that is more reliable.

```
function typingSentences() {
    var typed = new Typed('#typed', {
        stringsElement: '#typed-strings',
        typeSpeed: 50,
        cursorChar: '|',
        backSpeed: 10,
    });
}
```

```html
 <div class="appearingText">   
        <a class="aboutClass">About</a>

    </div>
```

```css
.appearingText {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2.3em;
    font-size: 1.6em;
}

.aboutClass {
    margin-left: -35em;
    color: white;
    background-color: #9561ac;
    border-radius: .35em;
    padding: .4em;
    font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
    font-size: .7em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture what is typed by `Typed.js` by using the `onStringTyped()` callback method. Here is an example:

```
var typed = new Typed('#typed', {
    stringsElement: '#typed-strings',
    typeSpeed: 50,
    cursorChar: '|',
    backSpeed: 10,
    onStringTyped: function(pos, self) { 
        if (self.currentElContent === 'String to look for') {
            // Do your string appearance manipulation here
        } else {
            // Reset your string appearance if needed here
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however, I am still a bit confused. I have the javascript set so that it will change the background color of my element whenever it hits a certain string.  (document.getElementById("aboutId").style.background = '#9561ac'). But it does not work. Do i have to modify the parameters in the function, or am I missing something else? Thank you!